# Wordpress Theme/Plugin Install (about FTP Connection)

Tags: plugins, themes, ftp

I installed WordPress on my virtual machine. I connected it using SSH. I'm trying to install new template using WordPress Admin. When I click to download, it redirects me to FTP connection page.

I'm able to connect my machine using FileZilla and create/delete directory (permissions are OK). But, when I'm trying to connect using WordPress, I get error like `unable to locate wordpress content directory (wp-content)`

I googled and researched definitely and I tried all advice, but I could not find any solution. Can you help me?

Also, I tried to upload my theme using FileZilla, and I did. Although my theme is uploaded, it was not seen on Themes.

Comment: "when I'm trying to connect using WordPress" - you mean the FTP connection page from inside WordPress? I'd guess then you're not giving it the correct path to the WordPress installation in the FTP details.

Comment: Yes, I mean the FTP connection page from inside WordPress. How can I check FTP details in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

It should be related to folder permissions check the codex here it shows how to set directory permissions: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: As I said above, permissions are OK. Its not related to them.